# firebase company user login signup

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

i have been looking into documents of firebase for like days now and a bit confused as i am new in this. i want to signup a user of a company and then login with that user of a company. for example a company "abc" has multiple users, using angular 6

how can i create that user and then login with that company user...

please any help would be highly appreciated.

i don't want google , facebook etc login stuff.[firebase custom auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth)

using cloud firestore db.
i have tried custom authentication.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: If you want users to sign in with their company email address, you're looking for [email+password authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth). Note that they will have their own password for your project, since Firebase can't authenticate them against your company's servers (unless you implement that yourself with Custom Authentication).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i dont want user to signin with there company email address , the thing is like let say i have a company collection and a user collection and users are stored as company users ,, company has-many relation with users. and i want to signup and sign in with user